# Store Json (Retrofit response) in to Room Database

Tags: android, json, android-room

I'm new to Room database, I have JSON response from MSGraph API, which is List of Calendar events.

I want to store this response in Room database .

Sample response from the retrofit
data

```
{
   "@odata.context":"",
   "value":[
      {   
    
         "@odata.etag":"W/\"arcvR4W/==\"",
         "id":"AAvR4W-QUGEzDhwKmVNegAAFPBq3AAAEA==",
         "createdDateTime":"2020-05-28T11:15:19.3397025Z",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2020-09-08T15:57:16.2356808Z",
         "changeKey":"arcvR4W/==",
         "categories":[
            
         ],
         "transactionId":null,
         "originalStartTimeZone":"UTC",
         "originalEndTimeZone":"UTC",
         "iCalUId":"040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E831",
         "reminderMinutesBeforeStart":15,
         "isReminderOn":true,
         "hasAttachments":false,
         "subject":"Canceled:  discussion",
         "bodyPreview":"time didnt set correctly, so cancelling the call",
         "importance":"high",
         "sensitivity":"normal",
         "isAllDay":true,
         "isCancelled":true,
         "isOrganizer":false,
         "responseRequested":true,
         "seriesMasterId":"AAMkADU3MAAAAENAABqty9Hhb9BQYTMOHAqZU16AAAU8GrcAAA=",
         "showAs":"free",
         "type":"occurrence",
         "webLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/",
         "onlineMeetingUrl":null,
         "isOnlineMeeting":true,
         "onlineMeetingProvider":"teams",
         "allowNewTimeProposals":true,
         "isDraft":false,
         "hideAttendees":false,
         "responseStatus":{
            "response":"accepted",
            "time":"2020-05-28T11:15:00Z"
         },
         "body":{
            "contentType":"html",
            "content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div>time didnt set correctly, so cancelling the call</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
         },
         "start":{
            "dateTime":"2021-03-11T00:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone":"UTC"
         },
         "end":{
            "dateTime":"2021-03-12T00:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone":"UTC"
         },
         "location":{
            "displayName":"",
            "locationType":"default",
            "uniqueIdType":"unknown",
            "address":{
               
            },
            "coordinates":{
               
            }
         },
         "locations":[
            
         ],
         "recurrence":null,
         "attendees":[
            {
               "type":"required",
               "status":{
                  "response":"none",
                  "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
               },
               "emailAddress":{
                  "name":"abc",
                  "address":"abc@mail.com"
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"required",
               "status":{
                  "response":"none",
                  "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
               },
               "emailAddress":{
                  "name":"xyz",
                  "address":"xyz@mail.com"
               }
            }
         ],
         "organizer":{
            "emailAddress":{
               "name":"abc",
               "address":"abc@mail.com"
            }
         },
         "onlineMeeting":{
            "joinUrl":""
         }
      },
      
      more elements from list
      
      ]
      }
```

I searched the forum but did not get any right solution.
I want to store this response in Room database. Can someone help me the correct approach to follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should create "CalendarEvent" object and make response of retrofit be like this Call
after that you need to create entities from your models and create dao (contain methods  to insert,get,update and delete the data from db)
and in your repository when you receive the data map it to your db entity
with your mapper (you can use extension to map your own data)
I convert that json to kotlin data classes and you can create db entites inspired from those models

```kotlin
data class Address()

data class Attendees(val type: String?, val status: Status?, val emailAddress: EmailAddress?)

data class CalendarEvent(val id: String?, val createdDateTime: String?, val lastModifiedDateTime: String?, val changeKey: String?, val categories: List<Any>?, val transactionId: Any?, val originalStartTimeZone: String?, val originalEndTimeZone: String?, val iCalUId: String?, val reminderMinutesBeforeStart: Number?, val isReminderOn: Boolean?, val hasAttachments: Boolean?, val subject: String?, val bodyPreview: String?, val importance: String?, val sensitivity: String?, val isAllDay: Boolean?, val isCancelled: Boolean?, val isOrganizer: Boolean?, val responseRequested: Boolean?, val seriesMasterId: String?, val showAs: String?, val type: String?, val webLink: String?, val onlineMeetingUrl: Any?, val isOnlineMeeting: Boolean?, val onlineMeetingProvider: String?, val allowNewTimeProposals: Boolean?, val isDraft: Boolean?, val hideAttendees: Boolean?, val responseStatus: ResponseStatus?, val body: Body?, val start: Start?, val end: End?, val location: Location?, val locations: List<Any>?, val recurrence: Any?, val attendees: List<Attendees>?, val organizer: Organizer?, val onlineMeeting: OnlineMeeting?)

data class Body(val contentType: String?, val content: String?)

data class Coordinates()

data class EmailAddress(val name: String?, val address: String?)

data class End(val dateTime: String?, val timeZone: String?)

data class Location(val displayName: String?, val locationType: String?, val uniqueIdType: String?, val address: Address?, val coordinates: Coordinates?)

data class OnlineMeeting(val joinUrl: String?)

data class Organizer(val emailAddress: EmailAddress?)

data class ResponseStatus(val response: String?, val time: String?)

data class Start(val dateTime: String?, val timeZone: String?)

data class Status(val response: String?, val time: String?)
```

Comment: Do I need to create Entity for individual data classes ? or single entity class (i.e CalendarEvent)?

Comment: it's depend how you want to deal with your data 
but for me, you should create individual data classes
and for room db entites, you need to build it using entity-relationship model what I mean is you need to design you db schema 
before any implementation
link 
1- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

2- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships